# envió de mail desde una página asp.net - mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email

la página web no la hice yo, esta hecha en asp con MVC, el problema radica al enviar los mail,el sitio lo tengo en Plesk web host edition.

```
Nombre de usuario del servidor de correo: ejemplo@midominio.com.mx 
Servidor de correo entrante : midominio.com.mx 
Servidor de correo saliente:  midominio.com.mx (el servidor requiere autenticación) 
Protocolos de correo entrante admitidos: POP3, IMAP 
Protocolos de correo saliente admitidos: SMTP
```

lo interesante y que no entiendo es que el remitente es una dirección con otro dominio otro@ejemplo.com.mx , ¿No se supone que los correos los debe enviar ejemplo@midominio.com.mx?

los datos que se envían desde la página al servidor son:

```
Mail-Host: mail.midominio.com.mx
Mail-Credentials-User: ejemplo@midominio.com.mx
Mail-Credentials-Password: xxxxxxx
Mail-FROM: otro@ejemplo.com.mx
```

Con el siguiente código

```
var cliente = new SmtpClient();
cliente.Credentials = new 
System.Net.NetworkCredential(this.User, this.Password);
cliente.Port = this.Port;
cliente.Host = this.Host;

cliente.Send(mmsg);

this.Message = string.Empty;
this.IsCorrect = true;
```

La mayoria de los correos destino son gmail, homtail,etc. 
Al enviar los mail me sale el error

> "Secuencia de comandos errónea. La respuesta del servidor fue: This mail server requires authentication when attempting to send to a non-local e-mail address. Please check your mail client settings or contact your administrator to verify that the domain or address is defined for this server."

Por lo que leí el host se debe configurar para permitir correos externos pero me mencionan que antes si mandaba los mail.

Comment: Asi es los correos de autenticacion y de envie pueden no ser los mismos pero del lado del servidor de correo ambos deben ser correos existentes y algunas veces se debe configurar o revisar que estan habilitadas las cuentas para uso de procoto smtp.

Comment: Ahora para que no eliminen tu pregunta agrega un poco de codigo y el error que muestra al intentar hacer el envio, tambien haz una prueba local.

Comment: Grcias por la pronta respuesta.                                                              
Me dicen que se uso una "mascara" en el correo remitente por eso parecen ser diferentes los correos de auntenticacion y de envio, sin embargo el mensaje de error persiste.  Las pruebas las hago tanto local como en la página en host y en ambas arroja el mismo error.

Comment: ¿cómo construyes `mmsg`? ¿Ese objeto tiene una propiedad `from`?

Comment: Vamos por el inicio primero envia tu correo solo con la cuenta principal, tambien en tu servidor de correo entra directamente usando tu usuario y contraseña para verificar que la cuenta se encuentre activa.

Comment: mmsg.To.Add(this.To);
                mmsg.Subject = this.Subject;
                mmsg.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8; 
                mmsg.From = new MailAddress(this.From);

Comment: No ingresa al webmal creo esta mal la contraseña.

Comment: Ya lo resolví gracias Miguel Zarate, el webmail no estaba dejando salir los email, así que lo tuve que cambiar.